# Outer Apply combine 2 rows into 1 row and 2 columns

Tags: sql, common-table-expression, outer-apply

I am trying to write a query that combines multiple Outer Apply join results into single rows of data. I have played around with some CTEs but I just cant wrap my head around the solution.

I would like to have the multiple join results display as 1 row with the 2nd join result displayed in a 2nd column

```
SELECT 
     E.[EventId]
    ,S_ID.[EventType]
    ,null as [RootCause2]

 FROM [AOE_Workflow].[dbo].[Event] E

    outer apply
    (
    select * from [AOE_Workflow].[dbo].[EventTypes] S
    WHERE E.EventID=S.EventID
    ) S

    outer apply
    (
    select * from [AOE_Workflow].[dbo].[EventType] S_ID
    WHERE S_ID.[EventTypeId]=S.[EventTypeId]
    ) S_ID

ORDER BY eventID desc
```

[image]

Comment: is there - for sure - just one additional result possible? From the syntax I assume this is SQL Server? Which version?

Comment: this is SSMS 2014.  There can be up to 4 results for the same eventID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I do not get this wrong, your `outer apply`s can be specified more easily with simple `LEFT JOIN`s.

The *side-by-side* output can be done with `PIVOT`. With the given query there is **no implicit sort order**. That means, that it will be random, which is first, which is second (and third/fourth). In my SQL you can easily control the sorting when you change the `(SELECT NULL)` to something appropriate.

```
SELECT p.*
FROM
(
    SELECT 
         E.[EventId]
        ,S_ID.[EventType]
        ,'EventType_' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY E.[EventId] ORDER BY(SELECT NULL)) AS VARCHAR(1)) AS ColumnName
    FROM [AOE_Workflow].[dbo].[Event] E
    LEFT JOIN [AOE_Workflow].[dbo].[EventTypes] S ON E.EventID=S.EventID
    LEFT JOIN [AOE_Workflow].[dbo].[EventType] S_ID ON S_ID.[EventTypeId]=S.[EventTypeId]
) AS tbl
PIVOT
(
    MIN(EventType) FOR ColumName IN(EventType_1,EventType_2,EventType_3,EventType_4)
) AS p
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you still in the design phase, or are you limited by the existing data structure?

Each event type would seem to be its own entity, as would root cause, i.e.
EventType = 'No power' could have 'expired battery' or 'bad alternator' as root causes,
so you would join the root cause to the event rather than the event type.

```
CREATE TABLE Event
( eventId int NOT NULL,
  eventTypeId int not null,
  rootCauseId int not null,
  CONSTRAINT e_pk PRIMARY KEY (eventId)
);

CREATE TABLE EventType
( eventTypeId int NOT NULL,
  eventTypeDescription int not null,
  CONSTRAINT et_pk PRIMARY KEY (eventTypeId)
);

CREATE TABLE EventRootCause
( rootCauseId int NOT NULL,
  rootCauseDescription int not null,
  CONSTRAINT rc_pk PRIMARY KEY (rootCauseId)
);

select
     e.eventId
    ,et.EventTypeDescription as EventType
    ,rc.rootCauseDescription as RootCause2
from
    Event e 
left join
    EventType et
        on
            e.eventTypeId = et.EventTypeId
left join
    RootCause rc
        on
            e.rootCauseId = rc.RootCauseId
order by e.eventId
```

Comment: unfortunately I am not the DBA, just an end user trying to work with the existing data structure